# In C++ is it possible to modify many struct objects simultaneously using pointer magic?

Tags: c++

Apologies, this may be a silly question and possibly very basic.

I am using a library that has a `Rectangle` struct as follows:

```
struct Rectangle {
  int x;
  int y;
  int width;
  int height;
}
```

I have many of these rectangles in a `std::vector<Rectangle>` which will always have the same `x` value  as each other (but all the other variables can be different).

Is there a way for me to use pointer magic and create a variable `cur_x` and have the `x` of all objects in `std::vector<Rectangle>` change their value to whatever I set `cur_x` to?

The struct is provided by the library, so I can't modify it and I'm trying to avoid iterating over all the elements of `std::vector<Rectangle>` to change their `x` values. Creating my own custom struct is also not an option.

Comment: Afraid not. Since the `x` member of the struct isn't itself a pointer, there's no way to make it point to something else.

Comment: If you want to share a variable among all objects of a class just declare it static.Changing it in one will make it appear in all as it's a single memory location. However, you can never create new objects where the value will differ. It's the same in all objects. Not clear if that meets your needs.

Comment: Is it for the sake of performance benefit or just cleaner and simple code?

Comment: If you can't modify the class, your only options is to loop over it and change them all. Why is that a problem?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid iterating over elements of a vector and changing each member?    This smells very much like premature optimisation to me.'

Comment: It's not a big deal to iterate, but this is a pattern that I see happening again and again. I thought my code would be much cleaner if I could just alter them in one shot. It's not just `Rectangle`, there are many such objects and I iterate over them all the time.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't sound like it with the constraints you've layed out.  The only thing I could think of (but would still be dangerous and not a good idea IMO) would be if you could somehow enforce that all the `x` variables were contiguous in memory and then you could set them all at once with some memory setting trickery.  But given that you can't modify the `Rectangle` struct I don't see how this is possible.

Your situation boils down to the fact that you need to set memory in multiple locations, the only way to do that is to multiple sets (and is likely best served with a loop)

Comment: Actually, just a thought, could you not change what the integer x in the struct is pointing to? I.e. `&rect.x = &myXVar`?

Answer (score 1):

If the X value is the same across all of your elements in the vector, and it is going to stay that way, the best idea I can think of would be to typedef another copy of the `Rectangle` struct and change `int x` to be `int* x`, something like this

```
//Somewhere global-ish
typedef struct {
    int* x;
    int y, width, height;
} rectangle;

int cur_X = 10;

for (int i=0; i < rectangleVector.size(); i++){
    rectangleVector[i].x = &cur_x;
}

std::cout << *rectangleVector[0].x << std::endl;
```

Comment: The problem is that `Rectangle` is used by many functions in the library (Ex: `DrawRectangle(myrec)`. So using a modified version of the struct won't help if I still have to loop through the vector.

Comment: Ah, okay that does complicate things a bit lol, in that case, yeah @sedavidw 's answer would explain it better.

Comment: another option would be to download the source code for the library and modify it (ie, overload the functions it takes in) and then within them where they need an `x` value, just dereference it there. Ie, make a new struct something like `RectangleP` which is defined next to `Rectangle` from the library, and then copy paste the functions that take in a `Rectangle` and implement them with `RectangleP`. It's probably your only option aside from the above answer, which would be a slow solution comparatively to this one (minus the time spent to implement it)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood after reading other comments, first, you need to change all of them at once, and second, you can't use pointers. So I suggest to modify the Rectange in a different way.

```
struct Rectangle {
  static int x;
  int y;
  int width;
  int height;
};
```

The static keyword will ensure that only one memory space is allocated for all Rectangle Objects, so changing it once would set all the objects to the same value. Also since the member `x`, is still an `int`, All the functions would work the same way even after overloading. (Make sure that no function is creating temporary copies of Rectangle or setting x to a temporary value).

---

To create multiple groups of Rectangles each having their own `x`, you can use references. References will ensure that all the Rectangle objects in the `std::vector<Rectangle>` point to one memory location, while allowing different memory locations between two different vectors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Rectangle
{
    int &x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
    Rectangle(int &_x):x(_x){}
};

int main()
{
    int cur_1 = 10;
    int cur_2 = 20;
    std::vector<Rectangle> Group_1(100, Rectangle(cur_1));
    std::vector<Rectangle> Group_2(200, Rectangle(cur_2));
    
    std::cout << Group_1[0].x << " " << Group_1[50].x << "\n";
    std::cout << Group_2[0].x << " " << Group_2[50].x << "\n";
    Group_1[0].x = 12;
    Group_2[0].x = 14;
    std::cout << Group_1[0].x << " " << Group_1[50].x << "\n";
    std::cout << Group_2[0].x << " " << Group_2[50].x << "\n";

}
```

The output:

```
10 10
20 20
12 12
14 14
```

So if you change `x` of any element of `Group_1` or `cur_1`, all the members of `Group_1` will have their `x` changed, however at the same time you can have a same property for `Group_2` while keeping the different values than Group_1.

Comment: `static` is a good idea, but that will affect literally every `Rectangle` I create and won't even allow me to have 2 `Rectangle`objects with different `x`. I might want to have 2 sets of rectangles each with their own common x.

Comment: I tried using references, which allows you to have 2 rectangle groups with different x, but property to change all `x` without iterating.